# Stuck at recursion

Tags: loops, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive loop below with Java and stuck at one more step to complete my project.

public List help(int start, int count, List MDS) {

```
    boolean flag=false;
    List<Integer> ans = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(count==1){
        for(int i=start; i<vertices.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            temp.add(vertices.get(i));
            for(int n: getNeighbors(vertices.get(i))) temp.add(n);
            System.out.print(MDS);
            System.out.println(temp);

            for(int v:vertices) {
                if(MDS.contains(v)||temp.contains(v)) flag=true;
                else {
                    flag=false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(flag) { 
                check.add(vertices.get(i));
                ans.add(vertices.get(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    else {
        for(int i=start; i<vertices.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> temp = MDS;
            temp.add(vertices.get(i));

            for(int n: getNeighbors(vertices.get(i))) temp.add(n);
            ans = help(i+1, count-1, temp);

            if(!ans.isEmpty()){
                check.add(vertices.get(i));
                ans.add(vertices.get(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(check);
return ans;
}
```

I am trying to fix particularly the following part.
In my head, the loop should always come back to this line:

```
ans = help(i+1, count-1, temp);
```

and execute the following lines, but it does not do so after the second loop.

```
if(!ans.isEmpty()){
                        check.add(vertices.get(i));
                        ans.add(vertices.get(i));
                        break;
                    }
```

This is the first time asking a question here, so please advise if I need further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. There was a reference problem here:  List temp = MDS;
Changing it to for(int m: MDS) temp.add(m), so temp won't change as MDS is updated.

Putting here for anyone interested.

```
    else {
        for(int i=start; i<vertices.size(); i++) {
            List<Integer> temp= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int m: MDS) temp.add(m);

            MDS.add(vertices.get(i));

            for(int n: getNeighbors(vertices.get(i))) MDS.add(n);
            //System.out.print(vertices.get(i)+" & ");
            ans = help(i+1, count-1, MDS);

            if(ans.isEmpty()) {
                //List<Integer> temp= new ArrayList<Integer>();
                MDS = temp;
            }

            if(!ans.isEmpty()){
                ans.add(vertices.get(i));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```